# Pandas - Plotly subplots with grouped charts

Tags: dataframe, plotly, bar-chart, subplot

I have following two similar data frames containing data for two different teams

dataFrameA:

```
name         bat_pos_1 ing_1_runs bat_pos_2 ing_2_runs
jack           2           10            2         20
john           1           20            1         5
```

dataFrameB:

```
name         bat_pos_1 ing_1_runs bat_pos_2 ing_2_runs
jill           5           20            3         30
nancy          4            5            2         7
```

I am using the following code to render a poltly grouped bar chart

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

figTeamARuns = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Ist Inning', x=dataFrameA['name'], y=dataFrameA['ing_1_runs']),
    go.Bar(name='2nd Inning', x=dataFrameA['name'], y=dataFrameA['ing_2_runs']),
   ])
figTeamARuns.update_layout(barmode='group')
figTeamARuns.show()

figTeamBRuns = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='Ist Inning', x=dataFrameB['name'], y=dataFrameB['ing_1_runs']),
    go.Bar(name='2nd Inning', x=dataFrameB['name'], y=dataFrameB['ing_2_runs']),
   ])
figTeamBRuns.update_layout(barmode='group')
figTeamBRuns.show()
```

The above code renders two charts one below the other but I want same charts to appear side by side. I know that i can be done using plotly subplots but I don't know how to go about it. Here is code I am trying to use

```
figFinalBatting = go.Figure()
figFinalBatting = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
```

I am stuck on what to do next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/) is quite clear here. Once you define fig you need to add every trace and specify in with row, col of the subplot scheme you want it to appear.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(name='Ist Inning',
           x=dataFrameA['name'],
           y=dataFrameA['ing_1_runs']),
    row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(name='2nd Inning',
           x=dataFrameA['name'],
           y=dataFrameA['ing_2_runs']),
    row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(name='Ist Inning',
           x=dataFrameB['name'],
           y=dataFrameB['ing_1_runs']),
    row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(name='2st Inning',
           x=dataFrameB['name'],
           y=dataFrameB['ing_2_runs']),
    row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Works Perfectly Thanks ! I had tried to find but the other answers showed passing data array to subplot figure but didn't work. Didn't realize that just mentioning the same column for different traces will result in grouping the bars.

Comment: You are right here. In the docs there is not this kind of example.

Comment: Here you might consider to add a legend group or even better concatenate the 2 dataframes.